# JavaScript speech-recognition distinguishing single letter from words?

Tags: javascript, speech-recognition, webspeech-api

Using Speech recognition I have been able to make a simple UI. I wanted to add some finer control but hit a roadblock. When the user navigates using letters such as `c, a, t` and says them quickly, the speech recognition will think that the user said the word `cat` and not the letter `c, a, t`. Is there a way to distinguish between words and a collection of single letters?

Comment: For me, usually, when each letter is pronounced separately, no matter which speed, the letters are printed as `C a t`. Sometimes the letters are capitalized for no reason in random order, and sometimes it writes `tea` instead of `t`.

Comment: What speech recognition library are you using?

Comment: @HarryCutts I used the voice recognition from the web speech API which is included in chrome if I'm not mistaken.